# How to save $_POST content with fputcsv to csv file with dynamic number of columns in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm making program, which reads columns from CSV -file and there's a input text fields in the HTML -form for each column in CSV. i'm using POST -variable in my Submit button, which redirects the action to the process.php. I would want to save data and write new line to the CSV from each of fields in the $_POST -array.

Can anybody give me a simple sample code?

Comment: Can you give US some sample code? Read this please http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and at least add what you have so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$csv_arr = array (
    array('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'),
    array('value5', 'value6', 'etc'),
    array("etc", "etc")
  );

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($csv_arr as $fields) {
   fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

 fclose($fp); 
?>
```

---

Result like this:

value1,value2,value3,value4

value5,value6,etc

etc, etc